# TensorFlow Averaging with Dynamic Lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to do a Mean operation given the actual lengths of sequences. (Masking Zero vectors)

My inputs `sequence_outpus` are of (batch_size, max_len, dimensions)

I have a tensor that stores the actual lengths of each sequence in the batch. I used the function from https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/

```
 def length(sequence):
     used = tf.sign(tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(sequence), reduction_indices=2))
     length = tf.reduce_sum(used, reduction_indices=1)
     length = tf.cast(length, tf.int64)
     return length
```

I do this:

```
lengths = length(sequence_outputs)
lengths = tf.cast(length, tf.float32) 
lengths = tf.expand_dims(lengths,1)
sentence_outputs = tf.reduce_sum(sentence_outputs,1) / lengths
```

The graph compiles but I am getting NaN loss values. Furthermore my lengths become negative values when debugging with eval().

This seems to be a simple problem but I've been stuck with this for sometime and would appreciate some help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no issue. Your code is slightly over-complicated. The following code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# creating data
B = 15
MAX_LEN = 4
data = np.zeros([B, MAX_LEN], dtype=np.float32)

for b in range(B):
    current_len = np.random.randint(2, MAX_LEN)
    current_vector = np.concatenate([np.random.randn(current_len), np.zeros(MAX_LEN - current_len)], axis=-1)
    print("{}\t\t{}".format(current_vector, current_vector.shape))
    data[b, ...] = current_vector

data_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)


def tf_length(x):
    assert len(x.get_shape().as_list()) == 2
    length = tf.count_nonzero(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return length


x = tf.reduce_sum(data_op, axis=1) / tf_length(data_op)

# test gradients
grads = tf.gradients(tf.reduce_mean(x), [data_op])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(grads)
```

runs perfectly fine here without any NaNs. Are you sure, you are really using this code? If I need to guess, I would bet you forget the `tf.abs` somewhere in your sequence length computation.

**Be aware**: your length function, as well as `tf_length` in this post, assume non-zero values in the sequence! The calculating the sequence-length should be the task of the data-producer and fed into the computation graph. Everything else, I consider as a hacky solution.